# typescript interface cannot extend interface error

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, resharper, typescript2.0

I have an interface defined as below in file `A.ts`

```
export interface StkhHierarchy {
    Designation: string;
    Hierarchy: string;
    .....
}
```

and in another file

```
import {StkhHierarchy} from '../../A';

export interface IStkhHierarchyExtended extends StkhHierarchy {
    ReportsToName: StkhHierarchy;
    WorkingReportsToName: StkhHierarchy;
}
```

[image: resharper error]

I am getting error that interface cannot extend interface. `tsc` is not giving this error, its seems that this is resharper problem.

Can someone please confirm if this is resharper issue or something wrong with code??

If I have both original interface and extended interface in same file, then it is not a problem, only if they are in separate file, then I get this error. So is it like after `import` typescript/resharper is no longer able to identify it as an interface??

Comment: I just tried replicating your code and resharper didn't flag it as a problem. Your code is definitely fine. Guess resharper has got a little confused.

Comment: @RossScott I even tried to clear the cache multiple times, but still getting the error... vs2017 + resharper2017.2, may be the cutting edge problem :(, I also have similar situation in other files - but those r not flagged only this one.. very strange

Comment: For me too, resharper 2018.1 is really not consistent with Typescript :-(... This is really a pity...